# How to send Ionic push notifications using Parse-Server?

Tags: parse-server

I want to send push notifications from my ionic app to app now I wrote parse cloud code and  normal typescript but both are not working, actually m requirement is sending push notification to all devices and also specific device,please review my code below and help me

my cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("send", (request) => {

    enter code here

    return Parse.Push.send({
        channels: ["News"],
        data: {
            title: "Hello from the Cloud Code",
            alert: "Back4App rocks!",
        }
    }, { useMasterKey: true });
});
```

typescript code
calling cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.run('send').then(function (ratings) { debugger console.log("updated"); // result should be 'Update object successfully' }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) console.log("fail") });
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using a Parse Server version equal to 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a query parameter. That way the push knows which user to send the push too.

You don't need the query parameter for channels. Do your installation have the channel?

Feel free to open an issue on the JS SDK.